# how to implement walk/postwalk traversal using clojure.zip

Tags: clojure

I can't figure out how to implement the clojure.walk/postwalk function using clojure.zip:

```
(clojure.walk/postwalk
   #(do (println %)
        %)
   [1
    [2 [3 4 5]]
    [6 [7 8]]])
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
[3 4 5]
[2 [3 4 5]]
6
7
8
[7 8]
[6 [7 8]]
[1 [2 [3 4 5]] [6 [7 8]]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn postwalk [f loc]
  (let [loc (if-some [loc (z/down loc)]
              (loop [loc loc]
                (let [loc (postwalk f loc)]
                  (if-some [loc (z/right loc)]
                    (recur loc)
                    (z/up loc))))
              loc)]
    (z/replace loc (f (z/node loc)))))

=> (postwalk #(doto % prn) (z/vector-zip [1 [2 [3 4 5]] [6 [7 8]]]))
1
2
3
4
5
[3 4 5]
[2 [3 4 5]]
6
7
8
[7 8]
[6 [7 8]]
[1 [2 [3 4 5]] [6 [7 8]]]
```

*Edit:* for prewalk, just perform the `z/replace` before going down.

```
(defn prewalk [f loc]
  (let [loc (z/replace loc (f (z/node loc)))]
    (if-some [loc (z/down loc)]
      (loop [loc loc]
        (let [loc (prewalk f loc)]
          (if-some [loc (z/right loc)]
            (recur loc)
            (z/up loc))))
      loc)))
```

Comment: I've spent the whole afternoon on this and right now, that code looks magic to me.

Comment: are you sure you want to use zippers?

Comment: @zcaudate prewalk added

Comment: I believe there is an interesting use-case for using them as it's a bit more generic than the clojure.walk version. I'm writing my own zipper implementation with the following differences: 

1. It operates based on spaces between elements:
     [ | <a> <b> ] = :move-left => [ <a> | <b> ] => :move-left => [ <a> <b> | ]

2. It uses conditional restarts to handle edge case conditions, such as when moving left on a left-most array:

https://github.com/zcaudate/hara/blob/master/src/hara/zip/base.clj
https://github.com/zcaudate/hara/blob/master/src/hara/zip.clj

Comment: for invalid state... it's very hard to define what the standard behavior is. Sometimes we want it to throw an exception, other times we want it to return nil, other times we want it to return to the previously okay state. So restarts are a good way to let the programmer define it themselves.

Comment: anyways. thanks so much for the implementations. they work a treat!

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a more idiomatic way to implement post order traversal that preserves zipper style navigation:

```clj
(defn post-zip
  [loc]
  ;; start from the deepest left child
  (loop [loc loc]
    (if-let [l (and (z/branch? loc) (z/down loc))]
      (recur l)
      loc)))

(defn post-next
  [loc]
  (if-let [sib (z/right loc)]
    ;; if we have a right sibling, move to it's deepest left child
    (post-zip sib)
    ;; If there is no right sibling move up if possible
    (if-let [parent (z/up loc)]
      parent
      ;; otherwise we are done
      (with-meta [(zip/node loc) :end] (meta loc)))))
```

This allows you to make conditional modifications in the same way you would with a normal zipper (i.e. you don't always have to `z/replace`, sometimes you can just call `post-next` with no change to the current node).

The implementation of postwalk given these helper functions becomes quite trivial:

```clj
(defn postwalk [f zipper]
  (loop [loc (post-zip zipper)]
    (if (z/end? loc)
      loc
      (recur (post-next (z/replace loc (f (z/node loc))))))))
```

This solution also has the advantage of not introducing recursion that could overflow the stack for large trees.